# Change the value of a cell whenever the Enter key pressed

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a named range (one cell) called "`Indicator`" which takes values `0` or `1`.

I want a piece of code to set the value of `Indicator` to `0` whenever the user presses the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key anywhere in the workbook.

Can someone please show me the VBA code to do this?

Comment: We're not exactly a code-writing service. But we're happy to help if you've started some and have come up against a problem you cannot figure out. So, have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Pressing enter key means moving down in a Worksheet, do you mean by changing the position of the selection value of old selected cell changes to 0 ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use OnWorksheet_Change
and specify the cell address,and enter the conditions
maybe that will help

Comment: This is really more of a direction to pursue so the reader can create their own solution than an actionable solution.  This would be more appropriate as a comment, which requires a little more rep.

Answer (score -1):

Suppose in Sheet1 you have a cell having 0 value (`Range("E4")`), then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>

click on sheet1, and from declaration dropdown select worksheet, and method as activate, then write below code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()   
    If Range("F5") = 0 Then
        Range("F5") = 1
    ElseIf Range("F5") = 1 Then
        Range("F5") = 0
    End If
End Sub
```